# can't create directories: Error: "You are not the owner so you cannot change this permission"

Tags: permissions

i wanna  create folder in  one  of  my hard disc partition but  i  can't because I'm not  the  owner. How do I do this?

Comment: You'll need the terminal and some knowledge of how commands work.

Comment: can you give  me  the  way  to do it  ?

Comment: This is not an error message that appears when you create a folder. The message appears, if you open the properties in Nautilus aka Files of a folder, for which you do not have permissions.

Comment: If you want a permanent way to be able to copy files and such (this isn't very safe or stable, but it is an option), you can use the terminal to run `sudo chmod 777 -R /path/to/folder` which will give you permissions to read and write to that directory, sub directories and files within the directory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will assume that you created a few partitions with Gparted, and you are not able to access them since the owner is root.

I had this problem myself and accidentally found a painless workaround.

Unmount partition, open Disks from dash, click the desired partition, then click the little gears > more actions > edit filesystem... and give it a new name. Mount back, and you are the owner for some reason.

Comment: X) yes that is what happened exactly   , @9248   i unmounted  the  disk ,change the  name  but  don't new  haw  to mount back ,haw to  mount back  ? >.< sorry  im beginner in linux

Comment: Click the files cabined from the Launcher on the left, it will open "Files". On left, under 'Devices' you should see the name of your partition, click it and a little icon will appear next to its name. That means it's mounted.

Comment: thanx  ^^ you solved  my  problem you are the  best  man  :)

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you don't. There's no need for you to be manually creating directories in system paths, or to change the permissions of any of the folders or files in those paths.

If there is some specific problem you are having, which results in you thinking this action is appropriate, then you are likely hitting a bug, or trying to do something wrong based on bad information. Please ask a question instead about the specific issue you're trying to resolve with this course of action you're attempting to take, to get better answers.

Comment: my problem  that  i can't create folder ,fille ,copy,or storing any thing in 2 partition of  my hard drive disk

Comment: Why do you think you need to create files in those locations?